# cmpfunc in qsort() function in c

Tags: c, sorting, libc, qsort

Can someone explain me `cmpfunc` which is used in the `qsort` function? What are `a` and `b` in this function and what are they pointing to?

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return(*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}
```

Comment: They are the two elements being compared in your function.

Comment: `a` and `b` are pointer to the elements of array.

Comment: @Idos Nitpicking: "*They are the two elements ...*" They are *not* the two elements themselves to be compared, but referring to, pointing to the elements to be compared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` and `b` in `cmpfunc` are pointers to `const void` type. `cmpfunc` can accept pointer to elements of array of any data type.
`void *` pointer can't be dereferenced, therefore a cast `int *` is needed before dereferencing.

Answer (score 3):

In this inputs are ***void** and you need to **comaper** integers in your case. So you will need to convert types. That's why there are

```
     *(int *) a
```

it can be float type

```
     *(float *) a
```

and so on other type...

you can find this implementation :

```
 int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b)
 {
  if(*(int *)a  <  *(int *)b) return -1;
  if(*(int *)a  == *(int *)b) return 0;
  if(*(int *)a  >  *(int *)b) return 1; 
}
```

Comment: You meant `void *` not `*void`, do you?

Comment: no I want just say void pointer, who can take address of any data type

Comment: `void *` is the type of a `void`-pointer, the type of a pointer to `void`, what `*void` is not. In fact the latter is not valid C.

Comment: so first they are referencing a pointer to the element  and then dereferencing it.