# how compare works in qsort() function

Tags: c++

I read the usage of `qsort()` in `<stdlib.h>` as described here [qsort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). The syntax for the function is:

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

This function requires a sorting function `compare()` as follows:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

With this function, qsort() sorts elements of array in a ascending order. I am confused about the `compare() function`, how does it help achieve ascending sorting. Anyone can explain the principle involved in a simple language? Thanks!

P.S.
It is noted a similar question has been asked here [cmpfunc in qsort() function in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565028/cmpfunc-in-qsort-function-in-c)

Comment: It's used to determine if an element has to go before or after an other element. I don't really understand what the question is.

Comment: You shouldn't use `qsort`.  Use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead.  Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects) for how you can customize it.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I am working on Arduino projects. I wonder if this function is applicable to Arduino?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  You'd have to port one of the open source standard libraries to use it.  It is a shame their library support is so incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic to it. The prototype is:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
```

The pointers `a` and `b` are *pointers to* adjacent elements in the array being sorted. What the `compare` function does is tell `qsort` how to evaluate whether the value pointed to by `a` sorts before the value pointed to by `b` (in which case the compare function should return `-1`). If the values are equal, then it should return `0` and finally if `b` should sort before `a`, the compare should return `1`.

(technically any negative or positive value can be returned)

However, your `compare` is subject to overflow. Best to test integer values as the result of two conditional expressions, e.g.

```
/* integer comparison ascending
 * (adapt for all numeric types)
 */
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(int *)a > *(int *)b) - (*(int *)a < *(int *)b);
}
```